# Does Rust have Collection traits?

Tags: collections, rust, traits, standard-library

I'd like to write a library that's a thin wrapper around some of the functionality in [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.BTreeMap.html). I'd prefer not to tightly couple it to that particular data structure though. Strictly speaking, I only need a subset of its functionality, something along the lines of the [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface in Java. I was hoping to find an analogous trait I could use. I seem to recall that at some point there were traits like `Map` and `MutableMap` in the standard library, but they seem to be absent now.

Is there a crate that defines these? Or will they eventually be re-added to std?

Comment: I seem to remember having heard that HKT might be needed to get useful collection traits but I am wondering if the current "associated items" would not be sufficient...

Comment: This question was included in the review queue as a 'test' question, i.e. the moderators felt that this question had no major problems. I disagree, This question strikes me as OT for SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, right now there's only [Iterator](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). `MutableMap` and `Map` have been removed somewhere along the road to stabilization of std for Rust 1.0.

There have been various discussions about re-adding traits to std. See these discussions on Rust internals:

- [Traits that should be in std, but aren’t](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/traits-that-should-be-in-std-but-arent/3002)

or (less recent but more specifically on collections):

- [Collection Traits, Take 2](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/collection-traits-take-2/1272)

Bottom line: everybody wants some form of those traits in std but nobody wants to commit adding and supporting the *wrong* ones in the standard library until a clearer picture of what is ergonomic emerges.