# Trait for a collection? Or more specifically, which trait enforces iter?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice

I want to implement a generic function that will calculate the total sum of any collection of numbers.

Ideally, the code would look like this:

```rust
c.iter().sum()
```

I've came up as far as compromising my ideal solution and ingesting a consumable iterator instead:

```rust
fn get_sum<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>, T: 'a + Sum<&'a T>>(i: I) -> T {
    i.sum()
}
```

This works, but it requires the caller to create an iterator out of the collection and pass that as an argument, e.g. `get_sum(numbers.iter())`

Is there a way that I can get `get_sum` to behave as close as possible to this?

```rust
numbers = vec![10, 20, 30];
total = get_sum(&numbers);
```

Comment: This *already exists* as the `IntoIterator` trait.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Does Rust have Collection traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35159530/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I might be lacking knowledge around this, but doesn't the `IntoIterator` trait specify an `into_iter` method? (IIRC, this method is different from `iter` because it actually moves the elements to the iterator). I'm looking something similar but for `.iter(&self)`

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster for the related link! I believe this does answer my question, I guess i'll just have to take an `Iterator` :)

Comment: [Applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45e5513881244936694ef291b47c8156)